# How to find slope changes?

Tags: matlab

I have calculated average horizontal values, their local minima points and plotted them. Now i have to find the valleys like first valley is negative to positive and 2nd valley is positive to negative. For this I have read somewhere that these valleys can be found by finding the slope change? can anyone help me out how to find the slope changes at specified points.

[image: Plotted graph]

Comment: if you have data you can calculate it's derivative and find points where it change sign

Comment: basically I want MATLAB to find those points for me by knowing only where negative to positive change and positive to negative change happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it this way:

```
dx = diff(x);
dx = [0 dx];          %shifting because diff has one less element
dx1 = [dx(2:end) 0];  %shifting dx for 1 element

r1 = find( dx>0 & dx1<0);  %compare dx and dx1 to find peaks
r2 = find( dx<0 & dx1>0);  %compare dx and dx1 to find valleys
```

So if you need only first peak you have take `r1(1)`, only second valley - `r2(2)` etc

Hope it helps!

Comment: aha! i forgot to ask you about your data format - i made this just for simple `x` vector smth like this: `x = [1 2 3 1 6 8 7 11]`. If you have a column or multidimensional array of course you have to change a little this code for your data. You can show your data format then I can check it!
by the way, my name is Mikhail ( k is not pronounced), Sam is just start of my hard-to-speak lastname :D

Comment: No problem bro! :D if you have problems write about it. if it works accept my answer ;)

Answer (score -2):

Slope sign change
MYOP, and WAMP features
(e.g. Hudgins et al., 1993; Philipson, 1987). It is another
method to represent frequency information of the EMG signal. It
is a number of times that slope of the EMG signal changes sign.
The number of changes between the positive and negative slopes
among three sequential segments is performed with the threshold
function for avoiding background noise in the EMG signal. This can
be mathematically expressed as
SSC ¼
XN1
i¼2
½f ½ðxi  xi1Þ  ðxi  xiþ1Þ; ð20Þ
f ðxÞ ¼
1; if x P threshold
0; otherwise:

Comment: Maybe consider editing your answer to address the question more clearly and concisely? For example, your maths code is not displaying correctly.